# Altering a class used as parameter type in a .NET web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

As far as I know, I can add parameters to a web method and they will be set to the default value when an outdated client calls the method (client endpoint has not been updated and does not know the new parameter).

What happens if the type of one of the parameters is a class/struct and I add a field to the class/struct? Does it work the same way and the field will get the default value or will the call fail?